# Manipulating data point in chart.js external tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.jsv3

I'm using Chart.js to display some financial data in a pie chart, along with external tooltips. The data in the tooltip is displayed currently like this:

> "Invoiceable: 1,202.5"

What I want is to firstly round the number to 1,200, and then add a '£' sign before the data point so it reads:

> "Invoiceable: £1,200"

I'm struggling to work out how to do this in this code below. Can anyone help?

```
 tooltip: {
            // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
            enabled: false,

            external: function(context) {
                // Tooltip Element
                let tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

                // Create element on first render
                if (!tooltipEl) {
                    tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
                    tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
                    tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
                    document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
                }

                // Hide if no tooltip
                const tooltipModel = context.tooltip;
                if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
                    tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
                    return;
                }

                // Set caret Position
                tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
                if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
                } else {
                    tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
                }

                function getBody(bodyItem) {
                     return bodyItem.lines;
                }

                // Set Text
                if (tooltipModel.body) {

                    const titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
                    const bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

                    let innerHtml = '<thead>';

                    titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
                        innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

                    bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                        innerHtml += '<tr><td><div class="tooltip">'+ body + '</div></td></tr>';
                    });
                    innerHtml += '</tbody>';

                    let tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
                    tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
                }

                const position = context.chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                const bodyFont = Chart.helpers.toFont(tooltipModel.options.bodyFont);

                // Display, position, and set styles for font
                tooltipEl.style.opacity = .8;
                tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
                tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.font = bodyFont.string;
                tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.padding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.padding + 'px';
                tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
            }
        }
```

FTR - I copied the above code from chart.js, which made it work, but I don't presume to understand it for a second!

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the `bodyLines.forEach` loop to alter the value it shows like so:

```js
bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
    let [label, value] = body[0].split(': ');
    value = `£${value.split('.')[0]}`
    innerHtml += '<tr><td><div class="tooltip">' + `${label}: ${value}` + '</div></td></tr>';
});
```

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Invoicable',
      data: [120000.5, 190000.7, 30000.2, 50000.3, 20000.9, 30000.1],
      borderColor: 'pink',
      backgroundColor: 'pink',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    locale: 'en-EN',
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
        enabled: false,

        external: function(context) {
          // Tooltip Element
          let tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

          // Create element on first render
          if (!tooltipEl) {
            tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
            tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
            tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table></table>';
            document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
          }

          // Hide if no tooltip
          const tooltipModel = context.tooltip;
          if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
            tooltipEl.style.opacity = 0;
            return;
          }

          // Set caret Position
          tooltipEl.classList.remove('above', 'below', 'no-transform');
          if (tooltipModel.yAlign) {
            tooltipEl.classList.add(tooltipModel.yAlign);
          } else {
            tooltipEl.classList.add('no-transform');
          }

          function getBody(bodyItem) {
            return bodyItem.lines;
          }

          // Set Text
          if (tooltipModel.body) {

            const titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
            const bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);

            let innerHtml = '<thead>';

            titleLines.forEach(function(title) {
              innerHtml += '<tr><th>' + title + '</th></tr>';
            });
            innerHtml += '</thead><tbody>';

            bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
              let [label, value] = body[0].split(': ');
              value = `£${value.split('.')[0]}`
              innerHtml += '<tr><td><div class="tooltip">' + `${label}: ${value}` + '</div></td></tr>';
            });
            innerHtml += '</tbody>';

            let tableRoot = tooltipEl.querySelector('table');
            tableRoot.innerHTML = innerHtml;
          }

          const position = context.chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
          const bodyFont = Chart.helpers.toFont(tooltipModel.options.bodyFont);

          // Display, position, and set styles for font
          tooltipEl.style.opacity = .8;
          tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
          tooltipEl.style.left = position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX + 'px';
          tooltipEl.style.top = position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY + 'px';
          tooltipEl.style.font = bodyFont.string;
          tooltipEl.style.padding = tooltipModel.padding + 'px ' + tooltipModel.padding + 'px';
          tooltipEl.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse! If I wanted instead to round the data point, so that 1,273,05 became £1,250 (ie, rounded to nearest 50) before adding the £, how might that be done? I tried editing 'value' bit I assume this needs coercing into being a integer first, but I'm struggling to do this.